# Info window two layers polygon and marker

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I've been using fusion tables layer wizard. The first layer is a map with markers within a city. The second one is the polygon of this city. In the new map, I only want the info window of the first layer to work. How can I suppress the info window of the polygon? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:500px; height:400px; }
    .layer-wizard-search-label { font-family: sans-serif };
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layer_0;
    var layer_1;
    function initialize() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.38240150737995, 11.039327819824182),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col1",
          from: "1MamWhdXCiB-m2Ak9gppNY9ZflBJsdGWvhSSR9NMB"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 3,
        templateId: 4
      });
      layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
          select: "col8",
          from: "1Xr-majg8ib430CcbcPP3OR50Eoe3biu0cczlhw1Y"
        },
        map: map,
        styleId: 2,
        templateId: 2
      });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable the default infowindows by adding the "suppressInfoWindows: true" option to the FusionTablesLayer constructor for the layer that you don't want to have infowindows.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#FusionTablesLayerOptions):

> **suppressInfoWindows** | Type:  boolean
>
> Suppress the rendering of info windows when layer features are clicked.

You also need to put the polygon layer on the bottom (add it to the map first).

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var layer_0;
var layer_1;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(49.38240150737995, 11.039327819824182),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  // polygons, no infowindow, put on bottom
  layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "col8",
      from: "1Xr-majg8ib430CcbcPP3OR50Eoe3biu0cczlhw1Y"
    },
    map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: true,
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  });
  // markers, infowindows, put on top
  layer_0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "col1",
      from: "1MamWhdXCiB-m2Ak9gppNY9ZflBJsdGWvhSSR9NMB"
    },
    map: map,
    styleId: 3,
    templateId: 4
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```